# How to have video play at same time as animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

If I have a moving picture/video that I want to implement into blender while I have an animation playing how would I do so? I tried making the video the background image, I put it as a material for the world and everything.

At frame 179 I want the cube to catch on fire. Which it does in the editor... but then I render it and nothing! Here is my set up:

[image: cube as particle system for fire]

And here is where I put my video:

[image]

Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: By nothing do you mean the cube doesn't catch fire or the box doesn't show up at all?

Comment: I mean that when I render nothing shows except for the black box. It doesn't present my video at all.